# Adicionar dias a uma data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

eu tenho o seguinte codigo,

```
  public today = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);


        this.formGeral.patchValue({data:this.today});
```

Ele retorna o dia de hoje, mas gostaria que retornasse 5 dia a mais do que o de hoje,
**EXEMPLO**
Hoje é dia 11/04/2022, queria que retornasse dia 16/04/2022, os 5 dias a mais não poderiam valer para dia que não são uteis (Sabado e domingo)
Seria possivel ?

Comment: coloque o código contendo a lógica(a qual trata a sua pergunta) que você fez de forma mais detalhada, para que possamos ajudar. Nós não criamos códigos e sim auxiliamos nos códigos postados pelo autor da pergunta para que funcione da forma correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) muda o dia do mês de uma data. Para adicionar cinco dias à data atual, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
let date = new Date()              // => 2022-04-11T20:55:10.902Z
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5)
date                               // => 2022-04-16T20:55:10.902Z
```

Agora você tem uma data que aponta para 5 dias no futuro. Basta verificar se é sábado ou domingo, e mudar pra próxima segunda-feira. Podemos fazer isso novamente com o `setDate()`.

```
const dayOfWeek = date.getDay()

// se sábado, adicione dois dias
if (dayOfWeek === 6) date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2)

// se domingo, adicione um dia
if (dayOfWeek === 0) date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
```

O método `getDay()` retorna o índice do dia da semana. Conforme a documentação, 6 é sábado e 0 é domingo.